# How to remove the default border radius ,Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I'mm using https://select2.github.io/examples.html but I don't want the border radius. [image]
How can I remove border radius to make the search box as well as the sliding area ?

Comment: Have you ever try something to make the job ?

Comment: Look for `border-top-left-radius`, `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-top-right-radius` CSS rules and fix accordingly.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

*You can add this css :*

```
[class^='select2'] {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

**fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/1537/

Comment: this also works in `css & scss`

Answer (score 2):

Well I've just tried to do a trick basically in jquery as below and yea it works!!

Execute below 2 lines once you initialize your `select2`

```
$('.select2-selection').css('border-radius','0px')
$('.select2-container').children().css('border-radius','0px')
```

Answer (score 1):

I really appreciate all the answers in this thread, as they helped me find a good solution.

I'm using Ruby on Rails 5.2.0, and I felt that any JQuery or JavaScript solutions felt a little hacky and after-the-fact especially since it should be doable in vanilla CSS - but I felt that using the CSS `!important` tag isn't best practice.  Not trying to rag on anyone!

So, my CSS is as follows, and works well!

```
.select2-container--bootstrap .select2-selection{
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your HTML Header:

```html
<style type="text/css">
   .select2-container {
       box-sizing: border-box;
       display: inline-block;
       margin: 0;
       position: relative;
       vertical-align: middle;
   }

   .select2-container .select2-selection--single {
       box-sizing: border-box;
       cursor: pointer;
       height: 28px;
       user-select: none;
       -webkit-user-select: none;
       display: contents;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Open file select2.min.css located dist/css/select2.min.css. locate the border radius you wish to change. example change "border-radius:4px" to "border-radius:0px"

section of code from select2.min.css below

```
.select2-dropdown{background-color:white;border:1px solid #aaa;border-radius:4px;box-sizing:border-box;display:block;position:absolute;left:-100000px;width:100%;z-index:1051;}
```

After a quick look through the CSS I can see 11 "border-radius:4px" change each one to "border-radius:0px" or just change the ones to the areas you wish. check CSS file.

Regards

Ben

Comment: Probably don't want to manipulate the original css files themselves, as that would affect all future behavior. I would recommend using either additional css commands afterwards or modifying the DOM via javascript after the page loads.